# Change button color with animation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have a download process in my application and I want to start changing the download button color when download start till it's completed. Is There any animation for changing button title color with start and end point? I don't know the animation duration as it depends on internet connection and file size. I have the following animation but it is not same as what I want:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    dlButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor MyColor];
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to change the `backgroundColor` manually when you need to update the progress.

First, get the download progress:

```
CGFloat progress = xxxx
```

Then you need to implement a method update the `backgroundColor` by progress like this:

```
- (void)changeColorByProgress:(CGFloat)progress {
    CGFloat red, green, blue;
    [[UIColor grayColor] getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:NULL];

    CGFloat completedRed, completedGreen, completedBlue;
    [[UIColor whiteColor] getRed:&completedRed green:&completedGreen blue:&completedBlue alpha:NULL];

    [self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:red + (completedRed - red) * progress
                                       green:green + (completedGreen - green) * progress
                                        blue:blue + (completedBlue - blue) * progress
                                       alpha:1]
                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Check my sample project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxq90sz3w65oa0k/TestManualChangeColor.zip?dl=0

Comment: Just use `setTitleColor:forState` instead of using `setBackgroundColor`.

Comment: Please check my sample project:https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxq90sz3w65oa0k/TestManualChangeColor.zip?dl=0

Comment: No worries, I’m glad to hear it solved your issue :)

Comment: Dear Bannings, it there anyway to give duration to this change color method?

Comment: How do you get the duration?

Comment: I want to handle it myself. no specific duration I want to make it happen in a fix duration.

Comment: In a fix duration? I think you should use your posted code.

Comment: That animation doesn't change the color from a value to another, I want to start from a color and change it to another value.

Comment: it's a function and I want to call it on a button action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86749/discussion-between-bannings-and-niloufar).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AFNetworking for downloading files, you can easily track its progress. Call delagate method in the block to update Background color of progress bar.

Check the link below: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.1/Categories/UIProgressView+AFNetworking.html

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request  progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response){
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]];
    return [documentsDirectoryPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:[targetPath lastPathComponent]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);

}];

[self.progressView setProgressWithDownloadProgressOfTask:downloadTask animated:YES];
[downloadTask resume];
```

You can also change the color by calling custom method and changing your progress bar color in that method.

Answer (score -1):

```
    [yourButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: So where exactly in your answer will this change of color be animated?